# Can change VBA explorer way to select dropdown list?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I try to make automation to select dropdown list.

I wrote below code. But in site, some contents was decided by dropdown list "CLICK".

So, how to do same "CLICK" function using VBA code?

Thank you in advanced. (PLEASE REFER THE PICTURE)

```
For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
    Debug.Print input_Data.innerText
    If input_Data.innerText = Cells(J, 2) Then
    input_Data.Focus
    input_Data.Selected = True
    input_Data.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")(1).getElementsByTagName("option")
    Debug.Print input_Data.innerText
    If input_Data.innerText = Cells(J, 3) Then
    input_Data.Focus
    input_Data.Selected = True
    input_Data.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Exit For
    End If
Next

For Each input_Data In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")(2).getElementsByTagName("option")
    Debug.Print input_Data.innerText
    If input_Data.innerText = Cells(J, 4) Then
    input_Data.Focus
    input_Data.Selected = True
    input_Data.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

```
<select class="form-control" id="txtDomain">                                         <option value=""></option>                                         <option value="9cca0f6f-5d1e-457e-ab42-3febb450ddb4">Benchmarking</option> <optgroup label="Innovation"><option value="43b1b494-2cc8-4ed1-ad5b-fa2716eb95d7">CAE</option><option value="6a1898a0-457a-4659-9c23-454769971804">Durability</option><option value="dd269de6-cd55-49ee-99a4-71cc8f7fcc9f">Materials</option><option value="1375a4ef-df95-4666-b836-219c0f625bee">NVH</option></optgroup><option value="95941150-193d-4364-bbef-c2b4c881bc5b">Laboratory</option> <optgroup label="Product analysis"><option value="d12df02c-1754-4e98-9795-d3f0f9f7af1e">CAE</option><option value="6f952267-cdf9-493d-8600-a7c5308f9b40">Canning</option><option value="8e88a836-7d14-427a-a96a-072f054239df">CFD</option><option value="783f1ea6-5236-4d3e-b8d1-dc176f03092b">Durability</option><option value="9c115779-d668-4b36-af69-a6e8920801c1">NVH</option></optgroup> <optgroup label="Testing"><option value="c747451a-598d-48f1-96b0-40594096af57">Emissions</option><option value="c7e1f63c-fc79-40e3-99f5-8f366c0e3f0f">Engine durability</option><option value="729c32e0-54c3-4753-9e83-bfd901e4425e">Fatigue</option><option value="3702e9f0-6271-42ff-b5b2-04ef121b0f69">NVH</option><option value="0c29ff9b-73fd-4f48-924f-519a53a7af25">Post Mortem</option><option value="34fba310-afb9-4d8f-bd2f-da3fd39122d7">RLDA</option><option value="96aa1d3d-6d7a-4a22-88a3-60cf4a01773d">Shaker/burner</option></optgroup>                                     </select>
```

[Drop down list graphic explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs0GM.png)

[Drop down list html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDvsI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better if you can show the html document, I assume you already try by click method:

```
input_Data.click
```

other option could be by seting the value manually in field as:

```
input_Data.value = "The option"
```

Or maybe you are just targeting the wrong element, if you could share the site or a picture of the html maybe I can suggest another method.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for response.There is a html. Can you check it?